# what is this syntax error? I don't even know what the error is. I m just beginning

Tags: python-3.x

```
number = input("Please enter your number:") 
number = int(number) 
if number % 10 == 0 : 
   print("Yes the number is a multiple of 10.")
elif :
    print("No the number is not a multiple of 10.") 
else :  
    print("Invalid number!")
```

this code gives the following output:

```
  File "multiple_10.py", line 5
elif : 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: please have a look to the answer I updated

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a condition when you use elif--otherwise just use else. Check out the python docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=elif.

Answer (score 2):

`elif` need a condition, add a condition or use `else`

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is `elif` need a condition, but in your code that is missing

I don't know what condition is suitable for your code but I tried this and its working fine

```
number = input("Please enter your number:") 
number = int(number) 
number = number % 10
print(number)
if number == 0 : 
   print("Yes the number is a multiple of 10.")
elif number > 0 :
    print("No the number is not a multiple of 10.") 
else :  
    print("Invalid number!")
```